# Writing SQLite to virtual file

Tags: java, sqlite

I need to create a SQLite database and send via http. This database will be created by calling the servlet. I can create a new database file every time, and then send it, but it will need some kind of file versioning.

My question is: Is it possible to create a database in a virtual file, append to it a few records and then send it without creating a real file?

Comment: What stops you from creating a temporary file, sending it and deleting it again?

Comment: Without versioning of files as xxx_123.sqlite many clients may try to create a file at the same time with the same name, and if the previous customer created in the same file, this file can be removed during a writing other clients to this file.

Comment: You could incorporate the client's unique ID into the temporary filename, thus avoiding such collisions.